# Using unique partition keys will it create a range partition?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm considering using a timestamp for partition key for logging messages to always keep it ordered with the most recents first.

```
PartitionKey = String.Format("{0:D19}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
```

Since the key is not increasing every time with the same pattern, will the partitions still be grouped in a range partition in this case?

It's just for logging, there will be no updates, only inserts of new ones and maybe delete older ones eventually. The main properties to query is date range, user and entityName (where did it happen).

Comment: The problem I see with your implementation is that the query time will increase by every entry in your table since you will always have to do a full table scan. If you write a lot of logs it will get very slow... Try to group your logs (example: put as PartitionKey the day and include the time in the RowKey or use the user\entityName as PartitionKey, etc...). Ps this video really help me: http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/svc09;

Comment: having user\entityName bothers me because we can only do a partial search on the user in this case, how would I search with only the entityName?

Comment: It depends, you need to find a priority. I mean, lets say you do it like "EntityName_UserName" and you want to find all the EntityNames with "AAAAA", so you can query for a string greater or Equal than "AAAAA" and less than "AAAAB"... The problem is that then you will not be able to do the same for the UserName.

Comment: Lets say you will query by date, and you have 1000 record per day and you save the last 30 days, you will have 30 000 entries. When you query it like you described you will query 30 000 partition. Lets say you group it by day, then you will have 30 partitions... See what will be more common and if you could make a partition key with a group of entities (maybe PK="User_Date" and later filter them with by entityName if you will always want the logs with a user).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Understanding the Table Service Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx) and [Designing a Scalable Partitioning Strategy for Azure Table Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh508997.aspx) - A [TableEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.aspx) already has a [Timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableentity.aspx) property.  Since you aren't doing updates the Timestamp should be sufficient for your date range query.

Comment: I would not recommend querying on `Timestamp` property as it will result in full table scan.

Comment: The goal here is to use the only indexes available, partition key and row key. Avoid full table spans.